# Creating Query on statement (TSQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a log file with different functions and steps:

[image: screenshot]

What I need is the Duration of the whole function. 
This is my Statement so far:

```
SELECT [Id]
      ,[Func]
      ,[Step]
      ,[Timestamp]
      ,CAST((SELECT [Timestamp] 
             FROM [LiPimDb].[dbo].[Log_Export_Catalog] 
             WHERE [Id] = [Log].[Id]+1)-[Timestamp]AS TIME(3)) AS Duration 

FROM [LiPimDb].[dbo].[Log_Export_Catalog] AS [Log]

WHERE Func = 'SP_Create_Export_Catalog'
```

Do I Need to get a subquery and then get the sum of Duration?

Comment: Which version of SQL server are you using and can you generate some sample data and some expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like simple `GROUP BY` is all you need:

```
SELECT
    Func
    ,DATEDIFF(second, MAX(Timestamp), MIN(Timestamp)) AS DurationSeconds
FROM [LiPimDb].[dbo].[Log_Export_Catalog] AS [Log]
WHERE Func = 'SP_Create_Export_Catalog'
GROUP BY Func
```

Remove the `WHERE` filter to see the duration for each function.

Answer (score 0):

From your table I'd say you need just the difference between `end` and `start`.

As this seems to be a stored procedure, the easiest might be something like this:

```
DECLARE @startTime DATETIME=GETDATE();
...Your code here ...
DECLARE @duration TIME=CAST(GETDATE()-@startTime AS TIME);
SELECT @duration;
```

This last value might be inserted into your log table for easy retrieval...